# When a user (completely) changes their answer via edit

Tags: discussion, comment, editing

Background story/motivation for question:

I recently saw an answer that presented an incorrect way of solving a problem.  (Simple algebra error, $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \not = x + y$.)

I let the author know via comment, and ended going back/forth a few times before he understood the error.  The user then edited the answer and responded with a comment that (in my opinion) implied that I was the one in error, not himself.  (I'm sure it wasn't meant to be ugly/mean, but could be interpreted in several ways--all he posted was an equation.)

Question:

**What is the protocol/accepted response when a user edits their own answer beyond recognition, and I've commented on the old answer?**

My comments don't apply to the new one (and could, theoretically, be deleted along with the whole (short) back/forth about the error), but I can't delete the whole conversation, so I'm hesitant to delete my side of it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can flag as no longer relevant and a moderator can delete the entire conversation.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps this can be solved in part by having some form of informal protocol for how users perform edits. When I change one of my answers due to comments, be it a minor typo, much larger flaw in a proof or just some extra, more general information about the problem/my answer, I usually prefix the edit with something like: "As blank points out in the comments...". This is as much to give credit where credit's due as it is to make the comments less confusing.